# Temporarily disable an input field if second input field is filled

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to disable an input while the user is filling another input. I've managed to disable one of the two inputs while the other input is being filled in.

The problem is that I want the disabled input to ONLY be disabled WHILE the other input is being typed in. 
So if the user changes their mind on the 1st input, they can delete what is in the current input which makes the 2nd input available and the 1st disabled.

**JS**

```
var inp1 = document.getElementById("input1");
inp1.onchange = function () {
   if (this.value != "" || this.value.length > 0) {
      document.getElementById("input2").disabled = true;
   }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
```

Comment: User can't type in 2 places at same time. Behavior logic doesn't make sense.

Comment: It sounds like the idea is to disable the first input as long as the second input contains text and vise versa. The absence of text in either would give the user the option to edit either field if I understand correctly.

Comment: What doesn't make sense? If the user types in one input, the other is disabled. If the user changes their mind and delete contents of that one input then the other input is re-enabled.

Comment: Note that with an `input `as `this`, `this.value != "" || this.value.length > 0` is just a long way to write `this.value.length > 0` (or a long way to write `this.value != ""`). :-)

Comment: Nothing in the quoted code ever sets `disabled` back to `false` when the input is blank.

Comment: OK...so only re-enable the other if user leaves the current one blank?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I understand what you're saying but I'm not entirely sure how that would be implemented correctly. I'm a beginner, sorry!

Comment: @charlietfl yes. Imagine a website is asking for a code, there are 2 formats for this code. The long format and short format. If the user types in the short format, the 2nd input is disabled. If the user changes their mind and then deletes what is in the 1st input, the 2nd input is re-enabled for use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would use `input` rather than `change`. Then, you need to set `disabled` back to `false` if the input is blank. Your check for whether it's blank is redundant, you just neither either side of your `||`, not both. (I'd also use `addEventListener` rather than assigning to an `.onxyz` property, so that it plays nicely with others. :-) )

So:

```js
var inp1 = document.getElementById("input1");
inp1.addEventListener("input", function () {
    document.getElementById("input2").disabled = this.value != "";
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
```

...and then of course if you want it to be mutual, the same for `input2`.

Comment: *(Doh! If you see "...if the input isn't blank..." above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: Nearly perfect except when I go to the 2nd input and start typing, the first input is still enabled rather than switch to disabled. The inputs need to be alternating between being enabled and disabled depending if a user is currently typing in them.

Comment: @SterlingKing: *"...and then of course if you want it to be mutual, the same for input2"* right at the end of the answer. Also note that your [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47701903/157247) with `keyup` is unreliable.

Comment: @SterlingKing: Your [newly-accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47702034/157247) is very much an example of how **not** to do this.

Comment: Why? It was the only one that worked the way I wanted it to. If you can give me a good reason then I'll reconsider.

Comment: @SterlingKing: Using an interval is completely unnecessary and CPU-wasting (consider the battery on mobile devices). If you applied the simple code above to both inputs, you'd get the result you say you want -- without unnecessary work. I don't care what you do, but it bothers me to see people promoting poor practices.

Comment: okay, I got my answer and I'll be respectful of your domain and practices. Your answer has been accepted.

Comment: I know this is old post but why when I do the same nothing happens ? my js code is in another file than the html but it seems that I have to call the function inside the input tag

Comment: @M.A.S - This still works today. Perhaps you've used an arrow function (so `this` isn't referring to the element) or...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My js was executing before my html page was fully loaded. Now it's working because I put the script tag at the end of the body. But do you have any suggestion of how to avoid that please ?

Comment: @M.A.S - Glad you figured it out! I really need to do a blog post on modern practices for the `script` tag. :-) Here's my take, in order best (IMHO) downward: 1. Use `type="module"` on your `script` in environments that support it (nearly all do now). Modules are automatically deferred (see #2) and also provide better encapsulation (top-level scope is not global scope) and are automatically in strict mode. 2. Use `defer` on your `script` in environments that support it (they all do, even IE10 and IE11). That defers execution of the script until all the HTML is loaded. ...

Comment: ... 3. Put it at the end, just before the closing `</body>` tag, as you did. Options if you don't control where the `script` tag goes (libraries, etc.): A. Provide a method that the code using the library uses to trigger initialization. B. Use a [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) handler to delay your code until the DOM is ready. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using focus and blur. Below it is done with JQuery.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#input1').focus(function(){
      $('#input2').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }).blur(function(){
     $('#input2').prop('disabled', '');
    });
    
    $('#input2').focus(function(){
      $('#input1').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }).blur(function(){
     $('#input1').prop('disabled', '');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
```

Comment: Good alternative +1 but doesn't actually disable the input. If the others can't figure it out, your answer will be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

How about using keyup?

Like this;

```
var inp1 = document.getElementById("input1");

var inp2 = document.getElementById("input2");

inp1.onkeyup = function() { inputValidation(this, inp2); }

inp2.onkeyup = function() { inputValidation(this, inp1); }

function inputValidation(origin, lock) {
  var response = hasValue(origin.value);
  lock.disabled = response;
}

function hasValue(value) {
  return value != "" && value.length > 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8o3wwp6s/

Comment: `keyup` isn't a reliable way to see notifications when the value changes (consider pasting, for instance).

Comment: I don't see why. Did you check the fiddle? it's disabling both inputs even when you copy and paste. Can you provide with a scenario where it fails?

Comment: Sure: 1. Copy something to your clipboard. 2. RIght-click an input. 3. Choose Paste from the menu. Now the input has text, but the other input isn't disabled -- because there was no `keyup` event. As I said in my answer, the correct event is `input`, not `keyup`, not `keydown`.

Comment: Makes sense. Mouse isn't a key. At least I got it 50% right, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it harder than it is, this is simple.

```js
var one = document.getElementById('one');
var two = document.getElementById('two');

//checks instantly 
var checker = setInterval(function() {
    if(two.value !== '') {
      one.disabled = true;
    } else {
      //when its clear, it enabled again
      one.disabled = false;
    }
    if(one.value !== '') {
      two.disabled = true
    } else {
      two.disabled = false;
    }
}, 30);
```

```html
<input id="one">
<input id="two">
```

Comment: There is **zero** reason to use a constantly-running interval timer for this.